# Client side (persistent) storage

Tags: javascript, storage, offlineapps

I've seen there are ways to store data on the client, e.g. using `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, or `indexedDB`.

AFAIK the main disadvantage of these technologies is that the browser may decide to clear out the stored data say if the device is low on memory (not sure if this is true also about `localStorage`).

I seem to fail to find information on some alternative storage which is more persistent: e.g. won't get deleted by a browser based on some decision.

Is there such a technology available? I am looking to use it next to ServiceWorkers for an offline first app.

I found something like [this](https://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/persistent-storage-api--building-for-the-offline-web/10161), is this something included with ServiceWorkers? (The article doesn't show much API). How is the support from browsers?

**clarification: I am fine if the data can be deleted by user, I don't want it to be deleted by browser automatically based on some decision.**

Comment: Only server-side storage would protect you against this. And, since you are working with an offline scenario, server-side technologies aren't going to help much.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Hm but the article claims otherwise? (also see google blog link inside that article)

Comment: @ScottMarcus e.g. this one: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage , just that article is a bit short on explanations and is also from 2016 so wondering how is it in 2018? Also where can I find more info on API etc.

Comment: I took your question to mean is there a way to prevent the data from being cleared, by the browser automatically or via any other means. This still wouldn't protect you against the user clearing the data as the article states: *the goal is to make users are aware of “persistent” data before clearing it - ideally letting them manually manage any such data*

Comment: In that vein, my original comment still applies.

Comment: i think indexedDB isn't cleared by the simple "clear cookies" user interface, at least in FF if not elsewhere.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, I didn't mean that user should not be able to delete it, that is fine. Just the browser should not do it. I don't know why you assumed what you did, but ok.

Comment: have you considered using nw.js or electron?

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually I have, Electron, just the current solutions for combining electron and react.js seemed a bit complicated initially to me, are you aware of some good tutorial on how to use react.js with electron?

Comment: @DanielA.White regardless I'd still be interested in answer to my original question (above).

Answer (score 0):

Since your app runs on clients' devices, and you don't have any real control on it, and your desire is impossible (' browser may decide to clear out the stored data' - not true. browsers might not be able to store data, or to get a reference to storages in some browsers and scenarios - e.g safari iframe and localstorage are not friends...)
Service worker do support indexedDB, so why not using it?

Comment: 'Service worker do support indexedDB, so why not using it?'--> because like I said browser could delete data in indexedDB on some occasions AFAIK

Comment: Browsers do not just delete data!
This is not true in so many ways.

Comment: this, https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/17/indexeddb-and-limits/, claims otherwise